# Can someone who unlocked the special Mercury Social Area bring others who haven't unlocked it?

Tags: destiny

When someone beats the Trials of Osiris with 9 wins and 0 losses a new level on Mercury will unlock for them. It's a new secret social space. I'm wondering if I was in a fireteam with someone who had unlocked it would they be able to take me there?

For example, for the weekly nightfall, sometimes if my alt hadn't finished the Eris Quests and the nightfall was in a level that came from the Crota expansion, then I wouldn't have been able to select it but my friend could take me in if it was unlocked for him because he had finished the Eris quests. Maybe this is also the case with Mercury?

Here's a video of the place I'm talking about:

Comment: My educated guess is that it won't allow to travel when someone in your group doesn't have access. The same happens when somebody is not high enough level for some mission or doesn't have required DLC. You will see name planks of the blocking persons flash when in orbit after you select the destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't show up. If the person is a host I don't think it will show up at all or won't allow to launch

Added from comment below:
"Yesterday I helped my friend finish his card and he went 9-0 but me and our other friend went 9-2 so we had to split the team."

Comment: Are you just speculating or do you know this as fact?

Comment: Fact, yesterday I helped my friend finish his card and he went 9-0 but me and our other friend went 9-2 so we had to split the team